# Use onTap() or onPressed() with FlutterIcons on a Bottom Navigation Bar

Tags: flutter, bottom-navigation-bar, ontap

I have a Bottom Navigation Bar using FlutterIcons and I would like to use either onTap() or onPressed() on them to switch between screens in the app. How can I achieve this?

Here's my code snippet:

```
      bottomNavigationBar: CurvedNavigationBar(
        backgroundColor: Constants.scaffoldBackgroundColor,
        buttonBackgroundColor: Constants.primaryColor,
        items: [
            Icon(
            FlutterIcons.ios_home_ion,
            size: 20.0,
            color: activeIndex == 0 ? Colors.white : Color(0xFF000B70),
          ),
          Icon(
            FlutterIcons.file_pdf_box_mco,
            size: 20.0,
            color: activeIndex == 1 ? Colors.white : Color(0xFF000B70),
          ),
          Icon(
            FlutterIcons.qrcode_scan_mco,
            size: 20.0,
            color: activeIndex == 2 ? Colors.white : Color(0xFF000B70),
          ),
          Icon(
            FlutterIcons.notifications_active_mdi, 
            size: 20.0,
            color: activeIndex == 3 ? Colors.white : Color(0xFF000B70),
          ),
          Icon(
            FlutterIcons.setting_ant,
            size: 20.0,
            color: activeIndex == 4 ? Colors.white : Color(0xFF000B70),
            
          ),
                  
       ],

        onTap: (index) {
          setState(() {
            activeIndex = index;
          });
        },
      ),
```

Comment: What  errors do you get from here, can you include the package link

Comment: When I add onPressed() to an Icon this is the problem I get: ```The named parameter 'onPressed' isn't defined.
Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'onPressed'.```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CurvedNavigationBar` doesn't provide `onPressed`, use `onTap` as you've define.

```dart
bottomNavigationBar: CurvedNavigationBar(
  items: [
  ],
  
  onTap: (index) {
    setState(() {
      activeIndex = index;
    });
  },
  body:yourWidgetList[activeIndex]
),
```

More about [curved_navigation_bar](https://pub.dev/packages/curved_navigation_bar)

Demo widget

```dart
class AGG extends StatefulWidget {
  const AGG({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AGG> createState() => _AGGState();
}

class _AGGState extends State<AGG> {
  List<Widget> pages = [
    Text("Page 1"),
    Text("Page 2"),
    Text("Page 3"),
  ];

  int activeIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: CurvedNavigationBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
        items: <Widget>[
          Icon(Icons.add, size: 30),
          Icon(Icons.list, size: 30),
          Icon(Icons.compare_arrows, size: 30),
        ],
        onTap: (index) {
          setState(() {
            activeIndex = index;
          });
        },
      ),
      body: pages.elementAt(activeIndex),
    );
  }
}
```

You can explore more about [BottomNavigationBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html)

Comment: Thank you for this, but I already have the ```onTap()``` as you have seen, however, this just simply works with ```activeIndex```. I wish to have the ```onTap()``` work for each Icon such that when I tap on it, I switch screens. How do I use ```onTap()``` for each Icon to perform that?

Comment: Have you create a list of screens?

Comment: I have the screens as files. All I want is to tap on the Icon and then call that file with the code for the screen to show.

Comment: Can you include full scaffold

Comment: I have added the demo widget, play with it, both functionality is the same

Answer (score 1):

The difference between onTap() and onPressed is the moment of execution. As you can imagine onPressed() fires as soon as user touches the item without necessarily removing the finger from tap area.

onTap() fires only after full tap has been detected meaning- item has been touched and touch was quickly removed. Quickly meaning faster than gets detected by onLongPress().

To use different touch types you can wrap every navigation item individually in GestureDetector or Inkwell or wrap the whole bar in one of those and pass a parameter to detect which item has been pressed.

Think of it as difference between tapping your arm and pressing on your arm.

Use whichever makes more sense in your scenario (I'd suggest onTap()). Hope that helps.

Comment: I get the difference and I believe I now know which to use, but my problem is when I call either onPressed() or onTap() on the icon (keep in mind this is a FlutterIcon, not "Icon"), I get an error line. Something like: ```The named parameter 'onPressed' isn't defined.
Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'onPressed'.```